# Submenu appears to be shifted to the right

Tags: css, wordpress

my sub menu looks on the right side, it looks like it is the sub-menu of the other menu.

[This is the exact problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnK7M.jpg)

This is the CSS line I found (I am definitely not a coder)

```
ul.tMenu li:hover > ul {position:absolute;display:inline-block; list-style-type: none; }
```

if its not enough, I can post upper parts and lower parts too. Thanks!

Edit: In safari, it’s look normal. But in the other web browsers, it’s broken.

[this is the full code line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZbXu.png)

```
#header {width: 100%; display: block;}
.sabitle {top: 0px!important;}
.sabitle {position: fixed!important;top: 0;z-index: 999999999999999;background: #cc6698!important;width: 100%!important;left: 0;right: 0;}
.tepeAlani {width: 1100px; height: 36px; display: block; margin: 0px auto; overflow: hidden; position: relative; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;}
.tepeAlani strong {float: left; width: auto; line-height: 36px; overflow: hidden; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; color: #999999;}
ul.tepeMenu{position:relative;width:auto;height:36px;list-style-type: none;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;padding:0px;display: block;float: right;}
ul.tepeMenu li{float:left;}
ul.tepeMenu li a {text-decoration: none;color: #999999;padding: 0 10px;line-height: 36px;font-size: 13px;display: inline-block;font-weight: 400;}
ul.tepeMenu li a:hover {color: #fe9900;}
.logoAlani {float: left;display: block;width: 350px;height: 90px;padding: 0px;overflow: hidden;}

.hMenu {width: 100%; height: 50px; display: block;}
a.home {text-decoration: none;width: 60px;text-align: center;line-height: 50px;font-size: 26px!important;display: inline-block;font-weight: 300;float: left;position: relative;z-index:99;}
ul.tMenu{position:relative;width:1100px;height:50px;list-style-type: none;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;padding:0px;display: block;}
ul.tMenu li{float:left;border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)}
ul.tMenu li a {text-decoration: none;padding: 0 19px;line-height: 50px;font-size: 16px;display: inline-block;font-weight: 300;}
ul.tMenu li:hover a{background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);background-position:left;}
ul.tMenu ul{padding:0;margin:0;display:none;}
ul.tMenu li:hover > ul {position:absolute;display:inline-block; list-style-type: none; }
ul.tMenu li:hover ul {position: absolute;top: 50px;width: 180px;height: auto;z-index: 99999;}
ul.tMenu li:hover ul li{margin:0;float:left;background-image:none;width:180px;border-right: 0px;}
ul.tMenu li:hover ul li a {padding: 0 10px;margin: 0;border: none;width: 160px;line-height: 40px;font-size: 14px;border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08); border-right: none;font-weight: 300;}
ul.tMenu li:hover ul li:hover a{background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)!important;}
```

Comment: (It's likely Safari is the broken one), but yeah this does not give us enough infos to help you.

Comment: Please share markup to reproduce the problem along with relevant CSS - otherwise you're not going to get much help.

Comment: @Dominik I added the header line as Image up here, I thought the other browsers are broken tho.

Comment: Hi, @UnbrandedManchester thanks for sharing. I am new here so I just learn how to put code here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work .hMenu {width: 50%; height: 50px; display: block;} instead of .hMenu {width: 100%; height: 50px; display: block;}.
if it doesn't work hit me up DM on [Instagram](https://instagram.com/paragrudani). I will definitely help you with this

Comment: can you show an example? which line or lines should I add what code? Sorry but I am not programmer hence you have to show me